# Error in DataAnnotations Validation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a project which is built in MVC 2015.  In this project, when I Created the page, at first I have set some controls as Mandatory by setting "Required Field Validation" using DataAnnotations in respective Model.  Later on I got a requirement that, I need to disable the validation on some of the controls in my View.  So, I have commented the "ValidationMessageFor" control and also commented the Required Field attribute in my model for that control.  My problem is, the validation for the control is working still even after disabled the same in my model.  Can any one help me, that how can I overcome this problem.  Below is my code.

//Code from my View

```
<td class="alignright2">
     <label id="lblAMCRate">AMC Rate</label>
</td>
<td class="paddingleft5px">
     @*<b class="requiredfield">|</b>*@
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AMCRate, new { @id = "txtAMCRate", @class = "textboxheight" })
     <br />
     @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AMCRate, "", new { @class = "validationfont" })*@
</td>
```

//Code from my Model

```
 // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error:You must enter a value")]
    public int AMCRate { get; set; }
```

And when I click on Save button after filling all Mandatory controls, the cursor is highlighting on the control, where I have removed the Mandatory.

[image]

Edit:

Validation is happening on some other controls too, where I remove the Required attribute
[image]

Comment: An `int` is always required (it cannot be `null` and the attribute is only necessary if you want to override the default error message. Make the property `int?` (nullable) if you do not want it to be required.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I agree the same, but validation is occurring for some other controls also, where I used a drop down control.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What does `List<string>` have to do with it?

Comment: What makes you think the validation for the first text field is still active? It only has cursor focus because it is the first field in the form. Your screenshots indicate that validation has passed for the first field, but has failed on OTHER fields, if the red bar indicates validation error.

Comment: @MarkE, its not the first control on the page. I just trimmed the screen shot and sent.  I already told that, after filling all the mandatory fields, I clicked on "Save" button and the cursor is focusing on every control, where I had disabled the "Required Validator"